# How to up load image to a folder and path to DB in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i have written some code in cakephp controller to store the image in folder and path to db ,my code was working as image name was storing in database along with all other fields.but the image was not storing in folder and path was not storing in db.only the name of the uploaded image was storing.

here is my controller code

```
  function addAdminList(){
    $this->layout = "ajax";
    if($this->request->data){
        $postArr = $this->request->data;
        $Curriculum = array();
        if($postArr['branchId'] > 0){
            $Curriculum['Shop']['id'] = $postArr['branchId'];
        }
        $Curriculum['Shop']['name'] = $postArr['branchName'];
        $Curriculum['Shop']['parent_id'] = $postArr['curiculumName'];

        $Curriculum['Shop']['owner'] = $postArr['owner'];
        $Curriculum['Shop']['startdate'] = $postArr['startdate'];
        $Curriculum['Shop']['phone'] = $postArr['phone'];
        $Curriculum['Shop']['desc'] = $postArr['desc'];
        $Curriculum['Shop']['address'] = $postArr['address'];
        $Curriculum['Shop']['timings'] = $postArr['timings'];
        $Curriculum['Shop']['image'] = $postArr['image'];
        $file = $postArr['image'];
        $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
        $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'); //set allowed extensions
        if(in_array($ext, $arr_ext))
    {
     //do the actual uploading of the file. First arg is the tmp name, second arg is
        //where we are putting it
        if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'img/upload_folder' . DS . $file['name']))
        {
            //prepare the filename for database entry
            $this->request->data['Shop']['image'] = $file['name'];
            pr($this->data);
            if ($this->Shop->save($this->request->data)) 
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The data has been saved'), 'default',array('class'=>'success'));

            }
            else
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The data could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'default',array('class'=>'errors'));
            }
        }
    }


        $this->Shop->save($Curriculum);
        echo 0;
        exit;
    }
}
```

and the form code is

```
<form id="addClsGrpFrm" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return disableFrmSubmit()">
        <div class="flash_msg"><?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="data[branch][id]" readonly id="branchId" value="0">
        <div class="login-form">
            <label>Select Shop Under</label>
            <select id="curiculumName" data-prompt-position="topLeft:200" name="data[branch][curiculumName]" class="validate[required]">
                <option value="">Please Select shop</option>
                <?php if(!empty($curriculumArr)){
                    foreach($curriculumArr as $res){
                        $id = $res['Shop']['id'];
                        $name = $res['Shop']['name'];?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $name;?></option>
                    <?php }
                }?>
            </select>

            <label>Shop Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="branchName" data-prompt-position="topLeft:200" name="data[branch][branchName]" placeholder="shop Name" class="validate[required]" />
        <label>Shop Image</label>
            <input type="file" id="image" data-prompt-position="topLeft:200" name="data[branch][image]" placeholder="" class="validate[required]" />
        <label>Owner Of Shop</label>
            <input type="text" id="owner" data-prompt-position="topLeft:200" name="data[branch][owner]" placeholder="Owner Name" class="validate[required]" />  

            <label>Shop Started Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="startdate" data-prompt-position="topLeft:200" name="data[branch][startdate]" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" class="validate[required]" />


            <label> Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="phone" data-prompt-position="topLeft:200" name="data[branch][phone]" placeholder="Phone Number" class="validate[required]" />

                <label class="lable1 fl">Content Description<sup>*</sup></label>
                <textarea id="desc" name="data[content][desc]" class="areaClass studentarea1 fr validate[required]" maxlength="255" ></textarea>

            <label class="lable1 fl">Address<sup>*</sup></label>
                <textarea id="address" name="data[branch][address]" class="areaClass studentarea1 fr validate[required]" maxlength="255" ></textarea>


            <label class="lable1 fl"> Timings</label>
            <input type="text" id="timings" data-prompt-position="topLeft:200" name="data[branch][timings]" placeholder="9:00 Am - 1:00 PM | 3:00 PM -9:00 PM " class="validate[required]" />   
             </div>
                <div class="login-form">
                    <input type="button" onclick="addAdminList()" class="login-btn" value="Submit">
                </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
```

how to upload image to folder and path to my db table.what to edit in my code to do this plz help me.

Comment: I don't think `$ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1);` is a good way to get the extension of a file because the filename may also contain a fullstop and this method will get you the undesired data. Maybe that is your problem?

Comment: Why are you not using the `FormHelper` to generate your form? It looks like you are making a lot of work for yourself which defeats the point of using a framework. Also, you should check out the `Upload` plugin for handling file uploads: https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload/. There's no point re-inventing the wheel!

Comment: Try https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage will abstract and store any files. It's more than just a simple uploader but a complete storage system solution with proper abstraction.